# Is there a simple way to find the location of any given application

Tags: apt, snap, flatpak, binary

The apps on my machine are a growing hodge-podge of snaps, flatpaks, appimages, cargoes, python-whatevers and so on. Some are in /usr/bin some are in /snap/ some are in ~/Applications or ~/.local/bin or wherever. So using the tools provided you need to go on a treasure hunt like `which applicationX` `apt search applicationX` `snap list | grep applicationX` etc. etc. In particular GUI apps can be really hard to find, as the name of the binary might not be the same as the actual ap.

So is there an easier, dare I say it canonical way to find the path to applicationX?

Edit: I'm using Gnome / Wayland (for the moment, if I get sick of everything looking like porridge I might go back to X11).

Comment: I manually keep a log of every `CLI` or `GUI` applications that I install. This also helps me install my favourite apps during a fresh install of the OS.

Comment: `ps -ef`? If on X11, `xprop` will tell you the PID. If on Wayland, you will either have to guess or DE-specific tools like KWin debug console

Comment: @rusty isn't this what we were promised by systems like snap and apt? I guess the issue is https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: Making "find the path to applicationX" for end-users isn't a priority on Linux. Once filesystem namespaces become widespread, following the containerization pattern of snapd, there can be multiple files at the same location, and you will need to use root and go to /proc. That would be just like UWP apps on Windows

Comment: I usually ask there system via `whereis`.  As multiple versions of an app can be installed; this can give the various results, with the current $PATH controlling which is found first.  Where GUIs are involved & used to start apps; there can be multiple icons/startups for the app that influence the end executable run making it more complex.

Comment: Thanks, but, `whereis` doesn't seem to work any more than `which`: `whereis signal` gave me the path to a .gz file that looks like it might be the manpages or sth: `> signal: /usr/share/man/man7/signal.7.gz /usr/share/man/man2/signal.2.gz` and `whereis krita` resulted in this garbage: `> krita:`

Comment: `whereis` will only search your $PATH, and that is a variable that can differ based on user account (inc. `sudo` or elevated privileges)... so if using a GUI *link*, *shortcut* etc that includes a path outside of $PATH it won't be found..   Yes it will also find `man` pages but they're pretty easy to recognize & thus ignore if they're not what you're looking for in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

"*So is there an easier, dare I say it canonical way to find the path to applicationX?*"

No. You have tried them all and found each lacking. There is no secret tool beyond them.

Do not assume that the system will keep track of how you installed a mix of software. **It won't**. Individual package tools will keep track of their own packages, but each is blind to others. Software installed from tarballs, from compiling, and other non-packaged methods are tracked only by the human admin.

This is a consequence of a system that does not constrain your choices. You, the human, must be responsible and judicious...and keep track yourself.

Experienced users learn to use those incomplete tools to expose key clues: Paths and names can tell you a lot. Different package types install to different locations. Hidden names can be revealed by Google. Dependencies can be traced. We channel our inner detective to reveal the truth.

Comment: Maybe I need to write a shell script to try all the usual suspects. The only problem is that there seems to be a new package manager every other day.

Comment: I simply keep notes on what I install and how.